# Triangle geometric problem

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC, AB=BC=12. Side AC extended through C a length equal to itself to a point D. Point E is on AB; DE intersects BC at F and BF equal to 8. Find AE ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is $AE=BE=6$ because in the triangle ABD, BC is a median and F is the intersection point of medians, therefore DE is also median. Since, $BF=8$ then $CF=4$, but we know that the intersection point of medians splits them into two segments which lenghts have quatient 2:1 from the vertex.

Comment: +1 Nice way of seeing it, in this special setup. You could fill in a bit more details about why F is the centroid (of what triangle).

Answer (score 2):

BC divides AD in half. So in triangle ABD, BC is the median.
BF:FC = 2:1, so F is the centroid.
Since ED passes through centroid, it is also a median.
Hence AE = BE = 6.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply [Menelaus' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem) to triangle $ABC$ and transversal $DEF$.

Comment: Yes, more "classical" theorems that don't get much "air play" nowadays...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner If you are a student training for olympiads, they are important. But once you are out of that phrase of your life, very few people care about Euclidean Geometry anymore.